# [CSS]Shortcut for multiple style

Tags: css

I don't want to write repetitive command such as.

```
button is-primary is-large is-dog
```

and I don't know to shorten it.

```
button is-primary is-large is-dog -> dog-button
```

Comment: Using Bootstrap? What if in another place you need a small dog-button?

Comment: There's no way to avoid repetition in selectors with CSS unless you use a preprocessor.

Comment: you need to look at PostCSS or SCSS or some other kind of preprocessor.